# How to order items on an online store by popularity

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have a series of items displayed on my homepage, which I want to order by popularity. I have a column called `sales`, which is a counter for how many sales the product has.

How can I use this and/or other columns to determine what items to display on the homepage? I obviously can't just use `sales` to search for popular items, because the items with the most sales will dominate the homepage - I want a balanced query.

If possible the query should also only occur within a certain timeframe, for example the past week etc.

Here's my query:

```
$popular_items = DB::fetch("SELECT * FROM `products` ORDER BY `sales` DESC LIMIT 10");
```

Comment: We don't know what other columns you have, or what you are trying to accomplish by "balanced query".  The only thing I can think of to help you would be to limit the top number of items of your current query and then create another one for the rest of the homepage.

Answer (score 0):

You have to define "popularity" first: by views, by sales, or by number of counts in shopping carts?

Assuming you have 2 factors: `pageview` and `sales`. You can order by these factors with a ratio, with respect to certain "fresh period":

```
SELECT * FROM `products` 
WHERE DATEDIFF(last_update_date, CURDATE()) < 30
ORDER BY (pageview * 0.7 + sales * 0.3) DESC
```

Something like that (as I don't know the column names in your table)

---

If you want to have balanced results, you can use:

```
SELECT * FROM `products` ORDER BY RAND() DESC
```

which will return random results. You probably need `LIMIT` too (pointless to list out all products).

Side note:

- it is suggested to select useful columns only (avoid using `SELECT *`)

Comment: I have selected only useful columns, I just used SELECT * for demonstration. If I use RAND() won't that just be selecting random results that aren't necessarily popular? Also, how can I make this occur over a specific timeframe?

Comment: that's why I ask what do you mean by popular. Can you define popularity in your case?

Comment: I have written that I'm ordering it by 'sales', so I'm using that as the definition for popularity. You mentioned pageviews which is a good idea, so I will implement that too

Comment: if you want balanced, you may want popularity over time. which would make your sales field not appropriate for the query

Comment: How can I set up popularity over time?

Answer (score 0):

If you have your sales have same value in some case then you can use

```
SELECT * FROM `products` ORDER BY  sales DESC,rand() LIMIT 3
```

which will return random results with sales Descending order. I was not sure what is your data you have I just tested at my end its word.